# Probability of $P(X_i< X_{i-1})$ for sequence of uniform distribution

Tags: calculus, probability

Let $(X_i)_{0\le i\le n}$ be a sequence of random variable that follow uniform distribution on $\{0,\ldots,9.\}$

I would like to compute $P(X_i< X_{i-1})$ which is not difficult to see that is $$\frac{1}{100}\,\text{card}((k,l); k<l)=\frac{9}{20}.$$

> It's the intuition, but how can I write $P(X_i< X_{i-1})$ to prove that is $\frac{1}{100}\,\text{card}((k,l); k<l)$ with no ambiguity ?

Comment: $\frac{9}{20}$ is the probability $P(X_i < X_{i-1})$. Do you want $P(X_i < X_{i-1})$ or $P(X_i \leq X_{i-1})$ as your question states?

Comment: @bames edited. thanks

Comment: This question does not have an answer without independence.For example the probability is 0 if $X_i=X_{i-1}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just write it as follows:
\begin{align}
P(X_i < X_{i-1}) &= \sum_{k=0}^9P(X_i <X_{i-1}|X_{i-1} = k)P(X_{i-1} = k) \\
&=\sum_{k=0}^9 \frac{k}{10}\frac{1}{10} \\
&= \frac{1}{100}\sum_{k=0}^9k\\
&= \frac{45}{100}\\
&=\frac{9}{20}
\end{align}